# How to process images in background with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload several pdf files, transform them into png using a service and stor the png bites array to database.
Problem is when the number of files increases, process time also increases.

Is there any way in which i can perform same task (upload 10 documents) and after the firs is completed, app can perform redirect and process other 9 in background?

Thanks!

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
                if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
                    // if (file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
                        if ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == "application/pdf") {

                            // call service to cast pdf to png and return $result
                                                
                            if($result){
                                
                                $document = new Document;
                                $document->client_id = 1;
                                $document->file_name = $name;
                                $document->file_content = $result;
                                $document->save();
                            }
                        } 
                    
                }
            }
        }


        return redirect()->route('test', [Document::first()] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing all the uploads in the background using [Laravel Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues). The simplest example would be creating a job which will handle all your controller logic instead:

```
php artisan make:job ProceessFiles
```

Now, to make this job work in the background, you have to make it queueable by using ShouldQueue trait:

> The generated class will implement the
> Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue interface, indicating to
> Laravel that the job should be pushed onto the queue to run
> asynchronously.

Your newly created job would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProceessFiles implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $files;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\Podcast  $podcast
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($files)
    {
        $this->files= $files;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Process uploaded files...
        if($this->files){
          // Do a foreach loop here and do whatever logic you need. The $this->files will be passed from the controller, so you will have access to all the data here
        }
    }
}
```

Now, change your controller code to call this job:

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_FILES['files']){
        //Here you can pass the files data
        dispatch(new ProceessFiles ($_FILES['files']));
    }
    return redirect()->route('test', [Document::first()] );
}
```

Now the whole process will be run in background. All you have to do is to start a queue. You can do that manually in your terminal:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Now, your queue is waiting for ProcessFiles job to be executed, and it will run automatically when you call it from controller. In order to better understand this process, you have a official documentation link at the beginning of my answer. If you have any questions, let me know. PS: This solution is not tested, so you might encounter some bugs.

Comment: Excellent answer! I will proceed this implementation and let you know how it went. Thanks for the really detailed answer!